# Why is my glob.glob loop not iterating through all text files in folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, glob

I am attempting to read from a folder containing text documents with python 3. Specifically, this is a modification of the LingSpam email spam dataset. I am expecting the code I wrote to return all 1893 text document names, however, the code instead returns the first 420 filenames. I do not understand why it is stopping short of the total number of filenames. Any ideas?

```
if not os.path.exists('train'):  # download data
  from urllib.request import urlretrieve
  import tarfile
  urlretrieve('http://cs.iit.edu/~culotta/cs429/lingspam.tgz', 'lingspam.tgz')
  tar = tarfile.open('lingspam.tgz')
  tar.extractall()
  tar.close()
abc = []
for f in glob.glob("train/*.txt"):
  print(f)
  abc.append(f)
print(len(abc))
```

I've tried changing the glob params but still no success.

Edit: Apparently my code works for everyone but me. Here's my [output](http://pastebin.com/81Zdd0Yr)

Comment: Your code works just fine for me: https://asciinema.org/a/39x9vuca48gd7fieugpkicbbt

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path?

Comment: I confirm too. It worked for me.

Comment: Hmmm. That's very odd. Why might it work differently for you guys than it works for me?

Comment: Read title as "glob.glob gloop". Upvote for entertaining title

Comment: Have you tried `glob.glob("train\*.txt")` with a backward slash instead? Or `glob.glob(os.path.join("train", "*.txt"))` to be platform independent.

Comment: @Event I just tried them both and got the same output: only the first 420 filenames print. I'm running on Windows 10/ Python 3.4.3 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! The problem was

```
if not os.path.exists('train'):  # download data
```

To check my output, I had actually downloaded the files onto my computer, and since this line checked whether or not the folder existed, and it did exist, it caused issues. I deleted the files off of my machine and now it works as it should, though I suspect running

```
  from urllib.request import urlretrieve
  import tarfile
  urlretrieve('http://cs.iit.edu/~culotta/cs429/lingspam.tgz', 'lingspam.tgz')
  tar = tarfile.open('lingspam.tgz')
  tar.extractall()
  tar.close()
```

without the if statement would have had the same result.